# Trying to create directories with Powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to create directories at some target location, if they don't exist.

The name of the directory is from another source-location.

for each directory name in `C:\some\location`
create a new directory of the same name in `C:\another\location.`

for example.

```
c:\some\location\
                \apples
                \oranges

to
c:\another\location\
                   \apples
                   \oranges
```

so in effect i'm recreating all the folders from `source -> to -> target`.
NOT recursive, btw. just top level.

So i've got this so far with PS:

`dir -Directory | New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path (Join-Path "C:\jussy-test\" Select-Object Name)`

or

`dir -Directory | New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path "C:\new-target-location\" + Select-Object Name`

and i'm stuck. I'm trying to get that last bit right. but anways, maybe someone has a nicer idea in their head?

Comment: one-liner: `dir -Path C:\some\location\* -Directory | % { New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path C:\another\location\ -Name $_.Name }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're very close with your first attempt.  The main thing you're missing is how to iterate over the output of `Get-Childitem` (aka `dir`).  For that, you need to pipe to `Foreach-Object`

```
$srcDir = 'c:\some\location'
$destDir = 'c:\another\location'

dir $srcDir -Directory | foreach {
  mkdir (join-path $destDir $_.name) -WhatIf
}
```

Inside the `foreach`, the variable `$_` holds the current object, and `$_.Name` selects the Name property.  (This also uses `mkdir` as a substitute for `New-Item -Directory`, but they're mostly interchangeable).

Once you know what this code is doing, remove the `-WhatIf` to have it actually create the directories.